# Hover effect causing image to float left when hovered over

Tags: html, css, hover, siblings

I have an image with certain spots over laid that when hovered over these spots pop up information. I have the hover working however when the spots are hovered over to show this information, the spots are getting pushed to the left instead of staying in place. I cannot understand why and would love any help please.

```
  <div class="model">
     <img src="images/baman.png">
  </div> 

  <div id="pain1">
     <img class="pain1" src="images/painspot.png">
     <img class="shoulder" src="images/shoulder.png">
  </div>  

  <div id="pain2">
     <img class="pain2" src="images/painspot.png">
     <img class="back" src="images/back.png">
  </div>

  <div id="pain3">
     <img class="pain3" src="images/painspot.png">
     <img class="hip" src="images/hip.png">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.model {
  position: absolute;
  right: 500px;
}

 #pain1 {
   position: relative;
   left: 65px;
   top: 130px;
 }

 .shoulder {
  display: none;    
  }

 .pain1:hover + .shoulder {
   display: inline; 
  }

  #pain2 {
   position: relative;
   left: -25px;
   top: 240px;
  }

  .back {
  display: none;    
  }

  .pain2:hover + .back{
    display: inline;
  }

   #pain3 {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: 240px;
  }

  .hip {
    display: none;  
  }

  .pain3:hover + .hip{
     display: inline;   
  }
```

Comment: what is the size of ur images

Comment: Could you provide a link to a working example?

Comment: I cannot provide a link since the site I am working on is not yet connected to a server. I tried to do a jsfiddle but since the images were not uploaded to anything it didn't really work out. The images that hovered over are 40 X 40.

Comment: Use `http://lorempixel.com/40/40` as a placeholder for your images then.

Comment: Ok, this is frustrating, here is the jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net HOWEVER, the issue I am having is not happening with these specific images but does happen when I am previewing my code. I am sorry if there is no way you all can help me. I really wish there was a way to let you all see the actual issue I am having.

Comment: @MelinaJesser You posted a link to jsfiddle home page in oppose to your code!

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle is here:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtgwqys0)

```
.model {
 /*code*/
}
```

Is not difficult to achieve, only copy and paste ;)
In the example is not floating any elements, are you sure that your images floating left? If is this case, be sure that no other code is overriding.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I know that in the jsfiddle I provided it does not show the issue I am having but I can assure you that the image is floating when it is hovered over. I have bad luck with posting questions on here because I am not able to provide the best kind of resources, thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: It seems that another code is overriding this hover event. You can inspect with your browser developer's tools. If you use firefox press SHIFT + F2, if you use chrome / ie press F12. Inspect the image that make your problem. Force the hover event and look to the properties that the browser is rendering. You can see the problem instantly.

You can put here a screenshot with your inspector if you don't know how read it.